# Tomcat Eclipse - Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Hallo I have installed the new Eclipse Luna in win8 (just mention everything cause I dont know what is the problem) and I have copied the whole project that I am working with at the workspace..have imported also install the plugin Tomcat and I am running it...what ever Site want to open always come this error...dont know what have done wrong or what I havent installed (jdk for example? or I dont know what )
[image: Same page error in every jsp site]

Comment: Did you compile it on Java8?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073222/java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse and http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/bugs/944/

Comment: no havent compile it on Java 8

Comment: yes I am using Java 8