# The type java.lang.object cannot be resolved - Eclipse buildpath not working

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I'm having a problem with Eclipse on by Mac OSX Mountain Lion. I have recently installed Android SDK and in my java projects I get the following message:

> The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
>   from required .class files

Reading about [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073222/java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse), it would seem that I do not have a valid JRE defined in the build path of my project. Checking the project's build path with Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries I see that The JRE System Library has a red cross next to it. However when I click Add Library... > JRE System Library I get the message:

> An error has occured. See error log for more details.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I then try clicking Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs and see an empty list. I try to Add... a Standard VM but I cannot find the location of my JRE. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ is empty and /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework does not exist.

Does anyone know how I might fix this problem?

Comment: Download a new JRE and add it in eclipse

Comment: I have downloaded a new JRE but do not know where it's root directory is.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me :

- Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
- Go to 'Libraries' tab
- Click on 'Add Library' -> JRE System Library -> Next -> Workspace default JRE (or you can add Alternate JRE) -> Finish

Answer (score 4):

*Right Button in the Project:* Build Path >> Configure Build Path >> Click JRE System Library >> Remove

*Then click:* Add Library >> JRE System Library >> Next >> Installed JREs >> Select JRE >> Ok >> Finish >> Apply

Answer (score 1):

You can follow instruction to [install a JDL (which includes a JRE) for Mac here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html*).

> Depending on your processor, the downloaded file has one of the following names:
>
> - `jdk-8uversion-macosx-amd64.dmg`
> - `jdk-8uversion-macosx-x64.dmg`
>
> Where version is 6 or later.
>
> - Download the file.
> - Before the file can be downloaded, you must accept the license agreement.
> - From either the Downloads window of the browser, or from the file browser, double click the .dmg file to launch it.
>     A Finder window appears containing an icon of an open box and the name of the .pkg file.

- Double click the package icon to launch the Install app.