# Imported project into Eclipse and shows errors right away

Tags: java, eclipse, macos-sierra

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.1 release 4.7.1 and I'm running jdk and jre version 9 64-bit on a MacOS Sierra system. I imported a project downloaded from the internet and it's showing 2 errors: 
1) The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project
2) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Has anyone ever experienced this? It must be a bug with Eclipse because all I did was import the project and it should work fine. I tried several ways to debug like clean the project and remove the JRE system library then add it again and refresh. Also tried restarting Eclipse several times and restarting my computer. Even reinstalled the JDK and re-downloaded and imported the project a few times. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337182/the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-eclipse-buildpath-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This is a rarely occurring bug in eclipse. Here are the steps to solve it, straight from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind) answer:

> - Close the project and reopen it.
> - Clean the project (It will rebuild the buildpath hence reconfiguring with the JDK libraries)
>
> OR
>
> - Delete and Re-import the project and if necessary do the above steps again.