# Eclipse JavaSE-18 cannot resolve PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm relatively new to Eclipse. I have a new clean installation of Eclipse on a Mac running Ventura 13.1.

In Terminal, java -version yields:

```
java version "1.8.0_381"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_381-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.381-b09, mixed mode)
```

In a simple test program without modules, and using only the default package, I begin with:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
```

The second of these imports is flagged as unresolvable (the first is accepted).

In my project, I see "JRE System Library [JavaSE-18]". Opening that (clicking the "reveal triangle >"), I see jar file "java.desktop"; opening that, I see package "java.beans"; opening that, I see a long list of classes including "PropertyChangeEvent".

However, all those classes have a reveal triangle EXCEPT PropertyChangeEvent. That would seem to explain why my import is flagged as unresolvable.

How might I resolve this problem?

Updates Sept 18, 2023: (1) Copying PropertyChangeEvent.java source code into my project's source file seemed to solve the issue, and (2) installing jdk-17_macos-x64 from Oracle, which shows Java version "build 20.0.2+9-78", also seems to work.

I don't think I yet understand the numbering schemes where "Java 8", "jdk-17", and "build 20.0.2" are the same thing.

Comment: According to the javadocs, those 2 classes exist in Java 18 SE.  Therefore, the problem is with your Eclipse setup.  Try the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337182, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322893 and similar questions.

Comment: If that fails, it is conceivable that you have a homoglyph problem ... and one or more of the (Unicode) code-points in the source text is not the character that it looks like.  This can happy when copy-pasting from "unclean" sources.   (And ... why are you using Java 18?  It is end-of-life.  Use Java 17 LTS or Java 21 LTS.)

Comment: @StephenC Technically, Java 21 isn’t released for general use yet.  A few more days…

Comment: OK ... Java 17 LTS ... or Java 21 LTS in a few days time.  (And I'd be inclined to wait until the inevitable first patch release has landed.  Just in case ...)