# unable to get system library for the project on eclipse ide

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

[image]I was working on an android tutorial and it wanted me to import the library from another project .The import worked and the project works correctly. But I noticed that doing that messed up several of my other projects (the ones that use Android 2.1) by apparently messing with the build path. Now instead of seeing "Google APIs [Android 2.1]" under the `gen` folder I see **`"Unable to get system library for project"`**.

**I verified the following:**

I right-clicked the project and went to `Properties` I see that the correct Project Build Target is checked(Google APIs [Android 2.1]), but "Unable to get system library for project" is still shown above the assets folder and **below gen and Android Dependencies.** Cleaning all projects doesn't help.

How can I fix this problem?
is there a way to fix this issue globally or do I have to do it one by one?

Comment: In my case I had to reselect Android SDK location in Eclipse properties. `Window `-> `Preferences` -> `Android` -> `SDK location`

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Try

1. Right click on your project
2. Go to properties
3. Click the Android section
4. Select a different target api (assuming one is already selected, as mine was - otherwise, select the one you want and jump to step 9)
5. Click OK
6. Do steps 1-3 again
7. Select your original target api
8. Click OK
9. Clean and build your project

Worked for me, anyway.

Derived the solution from: 
["Unable to get system library for project" after I upgraded to Android SDK 2.3 and ADT 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372574/unable-to-get-system-library-for-project-after-i-upgraded-to-android-sdk-2-3-a?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, I went to the target and found nothing selected!, selected my target all went fine.

Comment: If the "Project Build Target" does not list the Android API you are expecting, you may need to refresh the list of APIs by going to Preferences > Android > click "Apply" to reload the list of SDK Targets.

Comment: You might also find you have to close and reopen the project. I certainly did anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Error in .classpath on your project. It not connect to android sdk. Fix it and clean project. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are targetting an API version that for some reason is not mapped on your buildpath.

1. See which is the version of the SDK you are pointing to at the project.properties file.
2. Go to the SDK Manager at Window->Android SDK Manager
3. Check the Android API item that matches the version you want to use, OR, click on the latest one and then update your project.properties file.
4. Make sure your project build configuration is Project->"Build Automatically"
5. Retsart Eclipse (claning and rebuilding may not refresh all the project properties)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @Erhannis answer :

```
"
Right click on your project
Go to properties
Click the Android section
"
```

When I view the build target everything looked fine :

[image]

So I checked another build target , hit apply, and then re checked my original build target (Android 4.4.2) and re-hit apply. My project then compiled.

Answer (score 1):

For me the project.properties file was missing (it was code from a repo I checked out). So I just created one with this line:

```
target=android-20
```

After that, [Erhannis' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12613023/399105) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completing Erhannis answer: If you fixed the problem but it appears again when you restart Eclipse, then just go to the file `local.properties` on your workspace folder and verify that the location of the Android SDK there is correct.

Answer (score 1):

At times, when only single Android SDK version is installed on your system, and if it gets changed either by un-installing / re-installing Eclipse, or otherwise (directly through SDK Manager), then this issue might crop up.
.
This is accompanied by the message like this on Eclipse console:

```
YourApp] Unable to resolve target 'android-22'
```

.
A simple workaround to this issue is:

1. Open AndroidManifests.xml of the project, and in the:

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>    android:minSdkVersion="14"
>    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
> ```

change the targetSdkVersion to the one currently installed on your system

2. Next, open the project.properties file and update

> target=android-21
>   
>   to your current SDK version

3. Finally, clean and re-build the project

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Project-> Select Android tools -> Select Fix Project Properties

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the menu icon with the Android sitting in the grey box with a white arrow pointing down "Opens the Android SDK Manager".

[image: Opens the Android SDK Manager]

or, from the command line, run:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android sdk
```

Comment: i already imported but Error is  "The project target (Android 2.2) was not properly loaded"

Comment: Did you import "Google APIs for API 8 (or 7 for 2.1)?  Then you need to go to project properties/Android.

Comment: what do you mean by "it wanted me to import the library from another project"? Which library?  Do you need to add <uses-library a:name="com.google.android.maps" /> to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i downloaded a one sample application and i import the application into eclipse  then  i open that main.xml that time  i got this error  "The project target (Android 2.2) was not properly loaded"

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Android SDK Manager window that you see when you follow the steps above?