# Android app project in eclipse has many package errors, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was working on an app about a year ago, and kinda forgot about it for some time. I want to get back into it, but every import has an error. I feel like I am just forgetting something simple, but I dont know what it is.

standard java projects (non-android) work fine, but anything android related has errors. I tried updating to the newest sdk (23.0.2), but that did not fix the problems.

here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHyK3.png) of what is going on.

Edit: I also just insalled the newest build tools, and all the extras in the android sdk manager. This did not fix the problem.

edit 2: It seems that if I go to the Library build paths, the JRE System Library can't be added. If I added, the name of it changes to "Unable to get system library for this project" This only happens with android projects, and not with non-android projects.

Final edit: the problem was fixed [by changing the android target version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141906/unable-to-get-system-library-for-the-project-on-eclipse-ide])

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but after installing the newest build tools, you definately have to update your eclipse plugin. Unfortunately Google messed it up with Version 23, so you have to unistall the old ones and reinstall the new one

Comment: i actually just downloaded the newest bundle, which I assume comes already with the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps could help:

```
Right-click on project » Properties » Java Build Path
Select Libraries tab
Find the JRE System Library and remove it
Click Add Library... button at right side » Add the JRE System Library (Workspace default JRE)
```

After this clean your project.

Comment: Oh, theres something wrong with this. if i go back to the system libraries tab, instead of JRE Library, it says 'unable to get system library for this project'

Comment: Check out the first answer! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141906/unable-to-get-system-library-for-the-project-on-eclipse-ide]