# Android project stopped recognizing the compiler

Tags: android

I am using Eclipse, and all of a sudden, I booted the computer, and one of my projects is no longer recognizing the Java compiler.  All the other projects still recognize it, but just this one doesn't.

I have my build path set in the settings. And I did clean many times, and even rebooted my computer. But nothing helps.

Any idea how to get the project back to recognizing my Java build/compile path?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still open the project in Eclipse ?

Comment: @Yume117 Yes I can open it and browse it no problem. But every line has a compile error :)

Comment: is there Android package in the project ? Did you try to look at the build paths ?

Comment: @Yume117 Could you please explain what you mean by "is there an android package in the project?" I just want to make sure I am answering the right question

Comment: Sorry i misstalked, i means Android Libraries and dependencies, are they in the build path ?

Comment: @Yume117 Yeah, the build paths look ok,  and so do the libraries and dependencies.

Comment: Actually, just took a closer look at libraries/dependencies and there is one line which says "unable to get system library for the project" - any idea how to fix that, or whether that is the issue?

Comment: You sould verify all config of the project. Is the java compiler checked ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34358/discussion-between-genadinik-and-yume117)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unable to get system library for the project" is **common issu** in Eclipse when you try to update ADT, Android SDK or force quit Eclipse... etc

Look there

["Unable to get system library for project" after I upgraded to Android SDK 2.3 and ADT 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372574/unable-to-get-system-library-for-project-after-i-upgraded-to-android-sdk-2-3-a)

[The project was not built since its build path is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341644/the-project-was-not-built-since-its-build-path-is-incomplete)

Sometimes it can be the **path to jdk** that is missing when you import project from other computer/mac

Comment: Thanks, just selecting a different Android build version fixed it :)

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse is just so bad. Hope that android studio will be better !! ^^